# how to change Width Scale in Opencv Histogram.(640 X 480)

Tags: c++, qt, opencv

how to change Width Scale in Opencv Histogram.

My Code Result express width 0 ~ 255, but I want to change width 640 to use Scale. and I want you to find my mistakes on code, and suggest to me solution..

Please Help me.

```
void MainWindow::Basic_Histogram(IplImage* timage)
{
    IplImage* canvas;
    int hist[256];
    double scale=1;
    int i,j,max=0;
    QImage pimage;

    canvas = cvCreateImage(cvSize(640, 480), IPL_DEPTH_8U, 3);
    cvSet(canvas,CV_RGB(255,255,255),0);

    for(i=0;i<256;i++)
    {
        hist[i]=0;
    }

    for(i=0;i<timage->height;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<timage->width;j++)
        {
            hist[(uchar)timage->imageData[(i * timage->widthStep) + j]]++;
        }
    }

    max = 256 * 10;


    for (i = 0; i < 256; i++)
    {
        max = hist[i] > max ? hist[i] : max;
    }


     scale = max > canvas->height ? (double)canvas->height/max : 1.;

     for (i = 0; i < 256; i++)
     {
         CvPoint pt1 = cvPoint(i, canvas->height - (hist[i] * scale));
         CvPoint pt2 = cvPoint(i, canvas->height);
         cvLine(canvas, pt1, pt2, CV_RGB(0,0,0), 1, 8, 0);
     }

     pimage = IplImage2QImage(canvas);

     emit newEdgeFrame(pimage);

     cvReleaseImage(&canvas);

}
```

---

Below Picture show you my code result.

[image]

Comment: I'd guess you can change the horizontal scale when defining the CvPoints, with something like: `CvPoint pt2 = cvPoint(i * 640 / 256, canvas->height);`

Comment: thanks your explanation